# Tension - Normal Reaction dilemma

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, free-body-diagram

A hemisphere of radius 'R' is kept on a horizontal surface. A nail is also fixed at 'O' exactly above centre of hemisphere at some height. A small ball of mass 'm' is slowly pulled by an external force 'F' on the surface of the hemisphere. Then

(A) As ball moves up, tension in the string decreases

(B) As ball moves up, tension in the string increases

(C) As ball moves up, normal reaction between ball and sphere decreases

(D) As ball moves up, normal reaction between ball and sphere increases

String - massless
Friction - negligible

[image]

My attempt: Assuming the string make an angle $\theta$ (smaller angle) with the vertical at a particular instant, we can write two equations.

$T \cos\theta + N \sin\theta = mg \tag{1}$

$T \sin\theta = N \cos\theta \tag{2}$

Solving these two equations we get, $T = mg \space \cos\theta$ and $N = mg \space \sin\theta$

So, as ball moves up, $\theta$ decreases $\implies$ $\cos\theta$ increases and $\sin\theta$ decreases $\implies$ $T$ increases and $N$ decreases.

But when I think myself pulling the ball with the string (thought experiment), I feel that the Tension should decrease because the weight of the ball will be balanced by the Normal reaction more and more effectively as the ball moves up and the tension should be zero just before the ball lifts from the top of the hemisphere.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It looks a bit complex problem! I recommend you to put a second angle that represent the position of the ball on the hemisphere, and you have to get the reaction force from it.  From your equation it seems that you are pulling the rope "exactly tangential" to the hemisphere?

Comment: @patta yes... Can you see what's wrong?

Comment: For example, in your first equation, you don't have $N \sin \theta$ but $N \sin \alpha$, where $\alpha$ is the angle that represent the position  of the ball on the sphere, and can be obtained geometrically from $\theta$ and the height of the nail; same for the second equation, $T \sin \theta = N \cos \alpha$

Answer (score 0):

Let $\alpha$ be the angle for position of ball from horizontal of wedge and $\theta$ be the angle made by ball from vertical position.

$N \sin\alpha + T \cos\theta =mg$

As motion continues, $\sin\alpha$ tends to zero and $\cos\theta$ tends to one. For the sum $mg$ to be constant, $N$ will increase and $T$ will decrease.